# How to get the multiple prediction for simpleRNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Basically my system is like this

- 4 array input and return 1 array output
- each array is consists of 12 numbers

my model is here below

```
n_hidden = 512
input_shape = 12
input_len = 4 
model = Sequential()

model.add(SimpleRNN(n_hidden, input_shape=(input_len, input_shape), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(n_hidden, activation="linear")) 
model.add(Dense(input_shape, activation="linear"))
opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
model.summary()
```

prediction code.

```
in_ = basicdata[0].x[:1]
# in_.shape =  (1,4,12)

predicted = []
NUM_DATA = 100
cnt = 0
for i in range(NUM_DATA):
    out_ = model.predict(in_)  
    #it returns only 1 answer.
    #out_.shape = (1, 12) 

    in_ = np.concatenate((in_.reshape(input_shape, input_len)[1:], out_), axis=0).reshape(1, input_shape,input_len) 
    if cnt == 0:
        predicted = out_
    else:
        predicted = np.concatenate([predicted,out_],axis=0)
    cnt = cnt + 1
```

In this case , `model.predict` accepts `(1,4,12)` and returns the one array `(1, 12)` but,
I want to get `(10,12)` multiple candidate to sample from.

I guess  `return_sequences` and `batch_size` of simpleRNN are related but still in vague.

In my understanding.

- `return_sequences`

`return_sequences = False`

A,B,C,D => (E)

`return_sequences = True`

A,B,C,D => (A,B,C,D,E)

I want to have like this below

A,B,C,D => (E1,E2,E3,E4,E5)

- `batch_size`

`batch_size` affect the input shape though,

I want to change the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return_sequences = False` (classifier of sequence):

A,B,C,D => (E)

`return_sequences = True` (classifier of sequence elements):

A,B,C,D => (A1,B1,C1,D1)

If your model was trained to predict the next symbol, then:

A,B,C,D => (B,C,D,E)

It is possible to create a model of this kind:

A,B,C,D => (E1,E2,E3,E4,E5)

It is seq2seq models (e.g. for translation, where the length of the input differs from the length of the output). You have to create two RNNs: encoder and decoder. As far as I understand it is not what you want.

`batch_size` is training parameter and used to implement stochastic gradient descent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation. I might have misunderstood some points. And also in next step I need to learn `seq2seq`.